Angular app with Azure AD not redirected to give path after successful login
I have an angular webapp which is integrated with Azure AD/Entra Id for user login. My azure AD app has redirect URI as "http://localhost:4200/translate". Following are my routes -
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'translate',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [MsalGuard],
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: LoginComponent },
];

I want to show the LoginComponent on http://localhost:4200. When the user has successfully logged in I want to redirect the user to "http://localhost:4200/translate". The login is successfully happening and I get a valid token as well but after successful login the user lands on http://localhost:4200. After 2-3 click on my login button in LoginComponent the angular app automatically redirects to "http://localhost:4200/translate". I want to understand why is the app not redirecting to "http://localhost:4200/translate" at the first go itself?
My login method in the LoginComponent for reference:
 loginRedirect() {
    if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest) {
      this.authService.loginRedirect({
        ...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest,
      } as RedirectRequest);
    } else {
      this.authService.loginRedirect();
    }
  }


I am able to login the user using Azure ad in default route(localhost:4200), after successful login it redirects to /translate route (localhost:4200/translate).
I have referred this msdoc to handle redirect route requests.
In app.component.ts by adding below lines of the code I handle the redirect route after successful login:
ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.handleRedirectObservable().subscribe({
      next: (result) => {
        if (result != null && result.account != null) {
          this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(result.account);
          this.router.navigate(['/translate']);
        }
      },
      error: (error) => console.log(error)
    });

Below is the complete code of app.component.ts:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private authService: MsalService, private router: Router) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.handleRedirectObservable().subscribe({
      next: (result) => {
        if (result != null && result.account != null) {
          this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(result.account);
          this.router.navigate(['/translate']);
        }
      },
      error: (error) => console.log(error)
    });
  }
}

Below is my Login Component it handles the login redirect.
login.component.ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
})
export class LoginComponent {
  constructor(private authService: MsalService) {}
  loginRedirect() {
    this.authService.loginRedirect();
  }
}

home.component.ts:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private authService: MsalService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const account = this.authService.instance.getActiveAccount();
    if (!account) {
    }
  }
  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }
}

By Running ng serve command I got below page, I click on the Login button it redirects to login credential page.

After Successful login I got below page with specified route.
Output:


router.navigate did not help me. Instead, I used the below code which makes thing work as expected.
 loginRedirect() {
    if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest) {
      this.authService.loginRedirect({
        ...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest,
        redirectStartPage: '/translate',
      } as RedirectRequest);
    }


@NiteshRatnaparkhe Provide your comment as an answer it will help full to the Community.
